# JPA not flushes before native query with FlushModeType.AUTO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In our project we use hibernate 5.0.12 and Spring data Jpa.I found that jpa does not invoke flush before native query.But in JPA specification i read that with FlushModeType.AUTO flush() invokes before every query(JPQL or native SQL).i guess its problem in hibernate an hibernates version.Could someone clarify this problem?We have a lot of problem with this issue.

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) , you could always read the basics at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) tab and also read some related questions to your problem , in order to get some real answers. In your case your question just brings up more questions(like: environment? transactions scope? database ? logs? tests performed?) and also looking like a mis-configuration rather than a *problem in hibernate an hibernates version*

Comment: Hi,i have a basic configuration with MySql database.i tested with show_sql logs and saw all queries.I think problem in hibernate because i changed version to 5.2 and it fixed problem.But i whant to know what is really occur, and where is problem exist or existed.need more information about this issue

Comment: well in this case i can really answer you because i am currently using `Hibernate 5.0.12.Final` along with `Spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.5.9.RELEASE` and i can tell you its working properly on MySql , PostgreSql , H2 , HSQLDB. Cant really answer you why its working when you change Hibernate's version, but are you quite sure you aren't configuring anything else apart from changing versions?

Comment: No,only hibernate version and related spring version,i am using bare spring,without spring boot,maybe problem in spring?Also i have found this ticket and last comment from vlad mihalcea https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9315

Comment: Ye strange looks like the same issue. Have you printed the default `FlushModeType` for both versions?

Comment: For both versions FlushModeType is set to AUTO.Its seems problem more deeper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hibernate [`FetchMode.AUTO`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-auto-flush-work-in-jpa-and-hibernate/), which is the default flush strategy, does not trigger for native SQL queries.

Since 5.2, it all depends on how you bootstrap Hibernate. A JPA bootstrap will yield the JPA behavior which triggers the flush prior to any query while a native bootstrap will not.

For older Hibernate versions, even for JPA bootstraps, it behaves as the legacy flush mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It means that Hibernate does not follow to jpa specification for old version?

Comment: It passes the TCK, which means it us compliant. However, the JPA spec is not as strict as you might think. For instance, LAZY fetching is barely a hint to the provider.