# Hibernate Session not getting flushed before native sql query

Tags: java, hibernate

I recently faced a problem where hibernate session is not getting flushed before executing a native SQL query. The flushmode of created session is *AUTO*. For the entity A, code is like

```
A a=aDao.getById(session,id);
  a.setB(3);
  ...
   String query = "select count(*) as total from A a where a.b=3";
   session.createSQLQuery(query)
             .addScalar("total", StandardBasicTypes.).uniqueResult();
```

The problem is I am getting wrong results with the `count(*)` query because session is not getting flushed before executing the query. If I do

```
session.flush();
```

before `count(*)` query, then it works just fine. This is contrary to what I have read from https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-auto which states that

> the Session API will trigger a flush automatically when executing a
>   native query.

What could I be missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA not flushes before native query with FlushModeType.AUTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216213/jpa-not-flushes-before-native-query-with-flushmodetype-auto)

Answer (score 2):

Actually according to a [provided documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-auto) it works as expected. There are two examples with a `Session`. The first one is *Example 359. Automatic flushing on native SQL using Session* And it has two assertions. Note that the second assertion compares `zero` as expected value. And the second example is *Example 360. Automatic flushing on native SQL with Session synchronization* where second assertion has a `one` as expected value. So to achieve your expected behavior you must enable a synchronization as shown

Comment: Yes, right ! Missed it,  but isn't it completely against the statement written above Example 359, "the Session API will trigger a flush automatically when executing a native query"

Comment: I guess it's just a misprint or something like this. In a previous revision of the documentation there is a direct note: _The Session API doesn’t trigger an AUTO flush when executing a native query_ [Here it is](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/flushing/Flushing.html)

Comment: actually it'a not a misprint and [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216213/jpa-not-flushes-before-native-query-with-flushmodetype-auto) an explanation